# Can I dynamically load additional scripts into an existing worker?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

Running in the browser (only modern browsers, Edge+, Chrome & Android, FF, Safari, iOS - last 2 versions)

Is it possible to add scripts to an existing worker?

When you have DOM access, you can create a new `<script>` tag via JavaScript however from workers there seems to be no such capability.

From within the worker, I can use ECMAScript Modules like this:

```js
import('/script-2.js')

// alternative non CSP safe way
fetch('/script-2.js').then(response => response.text()).then(eval)
```

However iOS Safari and FireFox don't support ESModules inside web workers.

Is there an equivalent method that I could use supported by old browsers (and doesn't rely on `eval`)?

Comment: Where is this script running? In a browser? In NodeJS? Somewhere else?

Comment: Running in modern browsers (Edge+, Chrome & Android, FF, Safari, iOS)

Comment: In a browser JavaScript has no control over OS threads though - so I'm unsure why you mention that.

Comment: Updated the question to remove the part about controlling threads

Comment: It was right in front of me the whole time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

Answer (score 0):

You can load scripts into a Web Worker synchronously using

```js
self.importScripts('path')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts